# Flex-direction in safari 5

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

So I am trying to use flexbox but it was pointed out to me that it doesn't work on the iPhone or in Safari for windows. Upon investigation I managed to find that the thing that doesn't appear to work is flex-direction.

```
    .flex-columns {
        display: -webkit-box; /* Safari */
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
```

I have created this codepen:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/qdpYpR

As you can see from that example, the right hand "column" is not filling the height. I need a way to fill the height but make sure it works on safari. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you have to use

```
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```